# Matching a word against an array with JavaScript Regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

```
nameArray = new Array("Bob", "Ben", "Don");
for (i = 0; i < nameArray.length; i++) {
re = new RegExp("\b(" + nameArray[i] + ")\b");
checkWord = re.test("Bob");
if (checkWord) {
    alert("true");
} else {
    alert("false");
}
}​
```

It returned false 3 times. It should return true the first time the loop runs.
I dont know what's my error. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use double escape since you are writing a string:

```
new RegExp("\\b(" + nameArray[i] + ")\\b");
```

Comment: @raina77ow Actually \b will be [interpreted as a backspace character](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_Variables,_and_Literals#Using_special_characters_in_strings) and not the b character.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into what the  pipe (`|`) means in regular expressions. No loop required:

```
var nameArray = new Array("Bob", "Ben", "Don");
var nameExpression = nameArray.join('|');
var re = new RegExp('\\b(' + nameExpression + ')\\b');
var checkWord = re.test('A string containing the word Bob in it.');
if (checkWord)
  console.log('+');
else 
  console.log('-');
```

Also, you are not declaring your variables. You should declare variables with `var` or else you will generate global variables which is dangerous and considered bad style.

Answer (score 0):

I think a regex like this will work

```
re = new RegExp("^" + nameArray[i] + "$");
```